# Google Maps, PHP and Postgres

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, postgresql, google-maps

I would like to ask if it is possible to use Google Maps Geocoding Service along PHP and Postgres, SOMETHING like Pamela Fox (and Lary Stucker) made here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax?hl=pt-BR

The reason for thinking in a change MySQL/Postgres is because I've been talking to some people that recommended that I shouldn't use MySQL because, in their own words, it is "confusing and outdated".

Basically, I would like to create a project wich allows me to geocode addresses from a table. I know this is pretty easy to do with Fusion Tables, but I need the capability to drag the marker right in the map, and then get its new address back in that same table.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with MySQL. Just use PDO or MYSQLI to be safe.

Comment: The article you're mentioning clearly says that they do not use Geocoding Service. `Note: This tutorial uses location data that already have latitude and longitude information needed to plot corresponding markers. If you're trying to use your own data that don't yet have that information, use a batch geocoding service to convert the addresses into latitudes/longitudes.`

Comment: Sorry, perphaps I didn't make myself clear. I wanted to use the article as example - something that may be similar to what I want to do: Basically, I would like to create a project wich allows me to geocode addresses from a table. I know this is pretty easy to do with Fusion Tables, but I need the capability to drag the marker right in the map, and then get its new address back in that same table.

Comment: I would like to ask if it is possible to use Google Maps Geocoding Service along PHP and Postgres, SOMETHING like Pamela Fox (and Lary Stucker) made here:

Answer (score 4):

The article you provide uses MySQL :) There's absolutely nothing wrong with MySQL, it's being used worldwide in databases much bigger than your example. There's nothing confusing about it either and it's surely not out of date.

Postgres has its own pros and cons. Generally if you're new to both, I'd say MySQL is very easy to start working with, while Postgres can have quite a steep leraning curve.

My advice would be - don't bother, just do what article says (except maybe creating tables in InnoDB format, rather than MyISAM).

Comment: Good reply (+1), although I'd say if you're new to both consider investing in learning PostgreSQL/PostGIS because it is a lot more powerful for GIS applications, making the the steep learning curve  well worth it. All the maps on my site that use a DB are built with PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Comment: What learning curve? SQL is SQL, that's it. PostGIS has functions that MySQL doesn't have, but that's all. And there is nothing wrong learning something new! :-)

Comment: Well, let's say commandline interface of MySQL is more straight-forward than that of postgres, and basically SQL is of course SQL, but if you are going to dive deeper than simple select/update/insert/delete statements, Postgres also has many advanced features which have a, somewhat, unorthodox syntax of usage ;) But nothing is impossible of course.